Vertx eventbus seems to block when setPeriodic is running on WorkerVerticle
I have a scenario where I have an Http Verticle that in turn sends messages via the eventbus to a worker verticle.
On the Worker Verticle I have a setPeriodic that runs a fairly long job every hour. When this setPeriodic job is running the eventbus on the Worker Verticle side does not receive any messages from the Http Verticle side.
I can see that when the periodic executes the job, it starts on a worker thread. Im a little confused by why the event bus seems to block in this scenario and eventually times out after 30s.
Is this expected?

There is 1 instance of the worker verticle.

See code example and logs from a test run, I just generated a basic application using vertx.io started and added some code, iv provided the gradle config as well.
package com.example.starter

import io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions
import io.vertx.core.ThreadingModel
import io.vertx.core.Vertx
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer
import io.vertx.core.json.Json
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router
import io.vertx.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineRouterSupport
import io.vertx.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineVerticle
import io.vertx.kotlin.coroutines.awaitResult
import org.apache.logging.log4j.kotlin.logger
import java.time.Instant
import kotlin.random.Random



class MainVerticle : CoroutineVerticle(), CoroutineRouterSupport {

  private val port = 8888
  private val random = Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
  private val logger = logger(this::class.simpleName!!)

  override suspend fun stop() {
    logger.info("${this::class.java.simpleName} stopped on $port")
    super.stop()
  }

  @Throws(Exception::class)
  override suspend fun start() {
    awaitResult<HttpServer> {
      vertx.createHttpServer()
        .requestHandler(routes())
        .listen(port, it)

      logger.info("${this::class.java.simpleName} listening on $port")
    }
  }

  private fun routes(): Router {
    val router = Router.router(vertx)

    router.post("/run").coHandler { ctx ->
      logger.info("Receive request on ${ctx.request().path()}, currentTime: ${Instant.now()}")
      vertx.eventBus().request<RunEvent>("run-event", Json.encode(RunEvent(id = random.nextInt()))) {
        if (it.succeeded()) {
          logger.info("Eventbus response received, responding to client with ${it.result().body()}")
          ctx.end("Result: ${it.result().body()}")
        } else {
          ctx.fail(it.cause())
        }
      }
    }

    return router
  }
}

class WorkerVerticle : CoroutineVerticle() {
  private val sleep = 5_000L
  private val logger = logger(this::class.simpleName!!)

  override suspend fun start() {
    super.start()

    vertx.eventBus().consumer<RunEvent>("run-event") { message ->
      try {
        logger.info("Received on eventbus consumer: ${message.body()}, ${Instant.now()}")

        message.reply(Json.encode(RunEventResult(true, Instant.now())))
      } catch (e: Exception) {
        logger.info("Failed to handle run event: ${Instant.now()} - ${e.message}")
        message.fail(400, Json.encode(RunEventResult(false, Instant.now())))
      }
    }

    vertx.setPeriodic(10_000, 60_000) {
      logger.info("Before Periodic, will sleep for $sleep ms, now: ${Instant.now()}")
      Thread.sleep(sleep)
      logger.info("After Periodic, now: ${Instant.now()}")
    }
  }
}


data class RunEvent(val id: Int, val runEventCreatedAt: Instant = Instant.now())

data class RunEventResult(val success: Boolean, val runEventResultCreatedAt: Instant = Instant.now())

fun main() {
  val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
  vertx.deployVerticle(
    MainVerticle(), DeploymentOptions()
      .setThreadingModel(ThreadingModel.EVENT_LOOP)
      .setInstances(1)
  )
  vertx.deployVerticle(
    WorkerVerticle(), DeploymentOptions()
      .setThreadingModel(ThreadingModel.WORKER)
      .setInstances(1)
  )
}



Logs are from doing:

Hit http endpoint and receive response - returns immediately
Allow periodic to fire and then hit http endpoint and wait for response - this only returned once periodic had completed.
Hit http endpoint again - returns immediately

INFO  WorkerVerticle - WorkerVerticle started [# 14:34:52.369] [vert.x-worker-thread-0]
INFO  MainVerticle - MainVerticle listening on 8888 [# 14:34:52.469] [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0]

INFO  MainVerticle - Receive request on /run, currentTime: 2024-09-16T12:34:54.548702Z [# 14:34:54.550] [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0]
INFO  WorkerVerticle - Received on eventbus consumer: {"id":-412384914,"runEventCreatedAt":"2024-09-16T12:34:54.550736Z"}, 2024-09-16T12:34:54.608534Z [# 14:34:54.608] [vert.x-worker-thread-1]
INFO  MainVerticle - Eventbus response received, responding to client with {"success":true,"runEventResultCreatedAt":"2024-09-16T12:34:54.609044Z"} [# 14:34:54.612] [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0]

INFO  WorkerVerticle - Before Periodic, will sleep for 5000 ms, now: 2024-09-16T12:35:02.427843Z [# 14:35:02.431] [vert.x-worker-thread-2]
INFO  MainVerticle - Receive request on /run, currentTime: 2024-09-16T12:35:03.234533Z [# 14:35:03.234] [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0]
INFO  WorkerVerticle - After Periodic, now: 2024-09-16T12:35:07.432642Z [# 14:35:07.433] [vert.x-worker-thread-2]
INFO  WorkerVerticle - Received on eventbus consumer: {"id":-218888931,"runEventCreatedAt":"2024-09-16T12:35:03.234836Z"}, 2024-09-16T12:35:07.434098Z [# 14:35:07.434] [vert.x-worker-thread-2]
INFO  MainVerticle - Eventbus response received, responding to client with {"success":true,"runEventResultCreatedAt":"2024-09-16T12:35:07.434333Z"} [# 14:35:07.435] [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0]

INFO  MainVerticle - Receive request on /run, currentTime: 2024-09-16T12:35:09.920201Z [# 14:35:09.920] [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0]
INFO  WorkerVerticle - Received on eventbus consumer: {"id":1885275369,"runEventCreatedAt":"2024-09-16T12:35:09.920523Z"}, 2024-09-16T12:35:09.921379Z [# 14:35:09.921] [vert.x-worker-thread-3]
INFO  MainVerticle - Eventbus response received, responding to client with {"success":true,"runEventResultCreatedAt":"2024-09-16T12:35:09.921809Z"} [# 14:35:09.922] [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0]


gradle.kts
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.*
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
  kotlin ("jvm") version "1.7.21"
  application
  id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

val vertxVersion = "4.5.10"
val junitJupiterVersion = "5.9.1"

val mainVerticleName = "com.example.starter.MainVerticle"
val launcherClassName = "io.vertx.core.Launcher"

val watchForChange = "src/**/*"
val doOnChange = "${projectDir}/gradlew classes"

application {
  mainClass.set(launcherClassName)
}

dependencies {
  implementation(platform("io.vertx:vertx-stack-depchain:$vertxVersion"))
  implementation("io.vertx:vertx-web")
  implementation("io.vertx:vertx-lang-kotlin")
  implementation("io.vertx:vertx-lang-kotlin-coroutines")
  implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.17.2")
  implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
  testImplementation("io.vertx:vertx-junit5")
  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:$junitJupiterVersion")

  implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:2.23.1")
  implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.23.1")
  implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.23.1")
  implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api-kotlin:1.4.0")
}

val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"

tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {
  archiveClassifier.set("fat")
  manifest {
    attributes(mapOf("Main-Verticle" to mainVerticleName))
  }
  mergeServiceFiles()
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  testLogging {
    events = setOf(PASSED, SKIPPED, FAILED)
  }
}

tasks.withType<JavaExec> {
  args = listOf("run", mainVerticleName, "--redeploy=$watchForChange", "--launcher-class=$launcherClassName", "--on-redeploy=$doOnChange")
}


log4j.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%-5level %logger{36} - %msg [# %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t]%n</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN_SIMPLE">%msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleLogSimple" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN_SIMPLE}"/>
        </Console>
        <Console name="ConsoleError" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            </Filters>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef level="warn" ref="ConsoleError"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>


Would appreciate any insights!

Please share some code example for this.

@Anuj Iv added the code example to replicate behaviour I described

"There is 1 instance of the worker verticle."
=> Yes, default is 1 instance. You can increase instance numbers by options
new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(instances) // set 2,3,4 v.v...

About message is sent by event-bus. View my sample to get impl for all events. No need to use Json.encode/decode with event-bus
EventMessageCodec
Sub events extend from class AppEvent
Use with event-bus:
eventBus().request("ids", new YourEvent(), AppEvent.options)

eventBus().<YourEvent>consumer("ids", msg -> {...})

It is simple to use. No more serialize/deserialize manually.
More details in my microservices sample with vertx

Hey @Hung_PT, could you explain more on why worker verticle is not able to handle any request when it is executing the periodic task?
My assumption is by default worker thread pool has more than one thread. But Vertx does not allow worker verticles to perform more than one task at the same time or worker verticles cannot be used by more than one worker thread at a time.
Please confirm this.

Hey @Anuj, the document of vertx writes: Worker Verticles: These run using a thread from the worker pool. An instance is never executed concurrently by more than one thread Because there is one thread, so this thread is blocked to lead event-bus cann't handle event. Worker verticle doesn't fit to your purpose. Let's use ThreadingModel.EVENT_LOOP with Virtual Thread or use vertx.executeBlocking or declare new executor = vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("worker-pool")

This is a blocking operation: Thread.sleep(sleep). Let's use type Worker Verticle for simple tasks as batch sync data, send email v.v..... We can shutdown verticle after completing task. Not for tasks as: HttpServer, Event-Bus

Thanks guys, I had missed this previously when looking through the documentation but yes this snippet does answer my question:
"Worker verticle instances are never executed concurrently by Vert.x by more than one thread, but can executed by different threads at different times."
https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#worker_verticles

From the vertx.io documentation:
"Worker verticle instances are never executed concurrently by Vert.x by more than one thread, but can executed by different threads at different times
